# golang type conversion loop - apache modules

Tags: apache, go, apache-modules, cgo

I'm trying to construct a Go interface to the Apache module system. I.e. I want to be able to call Go functions from my Apache module. This is my Go file:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0
// #include <httpd.h>
import "C"

//export handler
func handler(r *C.request_rec) int {
    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html");
    ap_rprintf(r, "Hello, world from Go")
    return OK;
}
```

When I build it (`go build mod_frugal.go`) I get this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./mod_frugal.go:8:17: type conversion loop at volatile *struct apr_bucket
```

Line 8 is the line that function "handler" begins. Any suggestions?

Alternatively, when I build with cgo (`go tool cgo mod_frugal.go`) it doesn't see my include directives at all:

```
/home/vagrant/mod_frugal/src/mod_frugal.go:4:20: fatal error: httpd.h: No such file or directory
// #include <httpd.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

When I added the "C." prefix the two apache calls:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0
// #include "mod_frugal.h"
import "C"

//export handler
func handler(r *C.struct_request_rec) int {
    C.ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html")
    C.ap_rprintf(r, "<h1>Hello, world from Go!</h1>")
    return OK
}
```

I get a new error:

```
# _/home/vagrant/mod_frugal/src
37: error: 'ap_set_content_type' undeclared (first use in this function)
37: error: 'ap_rprintf' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Maybe I need to be linking against libhttpd? I just can't find anything on the internet about linking against apache2 for builds including like libhttpd.

EDIT:

Feel free to follow the conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/ru1_3cz7Hes/jRognWL4zCsJ):